# Sometimes I am not getting the foreground service notification on the android wear (galaxy watch 4)

Tags: android-wear-notification

We have android wear app and there is need - our app should work in the background.

so for that we used foreground service to achieve this behaviour.

we attached the notification with foreground service that we created, so we can identify foreground service is running on the android wear device.

most of the time it is working as expected, but some times it is not.